# Is it possible to lock down checkins against specific TFS 2010 work items?

Tags: checkin-policy

I'm a configuration manager currently learning about TFS functionality. We've chosen the CMMI process template and my 'problem' is that I don't understand the checkin / work item association permissions. For example, it seems I can associate my checkins against:-

1. Any work item type including the less obvious ones like Derived Requirement or Risk
2. Any work item type that isn't actually even assigned to me
3. Any work item type at any life cycle state (including Closed)

Is there any way to customise this or have I just not read the right chapter in my book yet? :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I dont know an policy which checks all of your requirements, but try the "Work Item Query Policy" described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163320.aspx).

The policy works like described

*Associates a work item from the specified query with your check-in. You configure the policy by selecting a team query from your team project.*

Now you can specify your query that you can solve 1 and 3.

**Note**

The policy will be available if the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools August 2011](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f?SRC=VSIDE)
are installed.
Additionally all clients (Developers) have to install the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools August 2011](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f?SRC=VSIDE) too.

At the moment i dont know a way for 2, only to write a custom policy like described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx).

**EDIT**

Based on the comment from DaveD, the second requirement (only assigned to me) is solved via
'Assigned To = @Me' condition.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the rapid response! Very impressed :-). I'll have a look at the information you have kindly provided. Thanks again

Comment: Thought you'd like to know I've managed to create a query that solves all 3 requirements by adding 'Assigned To = @Me'. Great! Thanks again